# how to soft-kill or soft-deny a target satellite?

Tags: spacecraft, future-missions, uncrewed-spaceflight

Thanks to the rapid growth of commercial space technologies, the use of space by new players is increasing. To prevent outlaw or problematic new spacecraft let's suppose there is a "space police" satellite in Earth orbit.
This space police satellite would need to perform a soft-kill or soft-deny which disables or denies a target spacecraft (in a non-destructive way)...
Just looking at the technical feasibility of this kind of idea, what would be a good way for this satellite to neutralize possible threats? Some ideas could be:

- Heating the target spacecraft,
- Interfering with the mission of the target spacecraft,
- Jamming the communication links of the target,

Are there any other ways to achieve a soft-deny of a target spacecraft?

My question would be mostly related about how to soft-deny a commercial/civilian satellite, what type of technology is currently used to prevent this type of attack from a threat?

Comment: This is why I've never understood the mockery of Trump's Space Force, by the way.

Comment: @WhitePrime I don't think there was much mockery of the a space force *per se*, it's been discussed seriously for a quite a while. Mostly it was mild cajoling about the particular name chosen and of course [that other aspect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AUXpnB065o).

Comment: In my opinion, every item you listed above is very dangerous. Since the soft-killed/denied satellite is operating while the "police" intervention, many things can happen.. Assume lost of control the satellite, it can be very dangerous to the  other ones, right? How it can be done without putting in a danger the other operation satellites?

Comment: No matter what mechanism you use to disable a rogue satellite, the harder part will be reaching it in the first place. Space is vast. LEO is not a single well-defined orbit that you could patrol, its volume is several times the volume of the atmosphere. Crossing that to reach a particular target (which might also be actively working to avoid you) is far from feasible, unless you intend to launch each police satellite on demand directly to the right orbit to rendezvous with the rogue one.

Comment: Heating a satellite to disable it seems almost certain to be destructive. Hopefully you'll just drive a LiPo battery into thermal runaway, but it's just as possible that you'll rupture a pressure vessel and convert the satellite into a cloud of shrapnel. Depriving it of power means disabling thermal control with potentially similar results. Even blocking communications can easily lead to irrecoverable loss of control, and would prevent things like collision avoidance maneuvers from being commanded. Basically anything that interferes with normal operation can be destructive.

Comment: This question needs a lot of clarification. What are the particular threat models of "outlaw" satellites you're considering? What kind of denial do you want to perform?